# Django clean removes an input field

Tags: django, forms, dictionary

I keep getting a key error when trying to access the 'email_password' part of the post data.  At some point cleaned_data produces a dictionary without 'email_password' in it.  How do I solve this?

```
class EmailForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    pword = forms.CharField(
        label=_('Old Password'),
        required=True,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput,
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        self.user = request.user
        return super(EmailForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cleaned_data = super(EmailForm, self).clean()
        data = cleaned_data['email']
        pword = cleaned_data['email_password']
        try:
            User.objects.exclude(id=self.user.id).get(email=data)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return cleaned_data
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("Email is already been used by another user"))
```

Comment: The fields in `cleaned_data` must use the same name as the form fields you've declared. And you named your password field "pword" not "email_password" Try renaming the field in the EmailForm, change the part where you read it to be cleaned_data['pword']

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem!